# What headers and/or cookies are passed when requesting an import map URL resource?

Tags: javascript, html

An [importmap](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps) allows you to specify where the import location of a Javascipt component or library actually is.  This can include a URL, as shown below:

```
<script type="importmap">
{
  "imports": {
    "foo": "https://example.com/bar.js"
  }
}
</script>
```

Thus `import('foo')` is a dynamic import of the contents of `bar.js`, which is hosted on `example.com`.

When that request to the remote URL occurs, what headers and/or cookies are actually sent in the request? Is there any way of configuring this? How does this vary if the domain of the resource does/doesn't match the domain of my website?